# If there is a point on a chord of a circle, which point on the minor arc would make the length between the the two points the smallest?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

If segment mn is a diameter of a circle f, and v is a fixed point on mn, for which point E on MN is the length FE minimized?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The chord is just a distraction.  For any point $D$ inside a circle (other than the centre), the closest point to $D$ on the circle is the point where the radial line from the centre through $D$ meets the circle.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. A proof would be: Let $F$ be any other point on the arc (different from our candidate $E$). Let $O$ be the center of the circle. Then we have
$$
OD+DE=radius
$$
whereas
$$
OD+DF>OF=radius
$$
(by the triangle inequality). Therefore, $DE<DF$.